# Hibernate ManyToMany results in cartesian product

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am a newbie in hibernate/JPA and apologies for this noob question. I have follow relations with in entities

- Manager has many to many relation with Worker
- Worker has many to many relation with Task

Following is the ERD

[image]

Following are my java classes

```
@Entity
@table(name="manager")
public class Manager {

private long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "manager_worker", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id") })
private ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();

 // ......getter setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "worker")
public class Worker {

@Id
private long id;

private String name;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "worker_task", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "task_id") })
private ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
  ...........................
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

@Id
private long id;

private String title;
          .................
}
```

I have following data:

- Manager M1 has worker W1 and W2
- W1 has tasks TW1, TW2, TW3
- W2 has tasks TW2 and TW2

When I get Manager object for Id M1, the result has cartesian product of Worker and Task i.e. W1 data is repeated for 3 times and W2 data is repeated for 2 times i.e. Manager.worker array list have 5 worker object instead of 2.

To load the data I am using Session.get() method

```
public E find(final K key) {
    return (E) currentSession().get(daoType, key);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this and point me to any best practices that I should use in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Try a `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` for `tasks` in `Wokrer` class.

Comment: Can you show us how you save the objects?

Comment: @Shazin I have not yet coded the save. The data is already in DB and I am trying to query it.

Comment: Can you show us how are you fetching objects from db?

Comment: I have added the code I am using to fetch objects.

Comment: Where is the @Id of Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because both `@ManyToMany` relationships are eager loaded.

This will cause an outer join over all three tables. The result of this query are five rows where W1 appear three times and W2 two times. So far everything is correct.

But for some reason Hibernate just puts all workers in the collections even if they are duplicates. It's even described in the [FAQ](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#jive_content_id_Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword).

There are multiple options to resolve this issue:

- change one of the relationships to lazy loading
- use a Set instead of a List (you shouldn't use `ArrayList` as type for variables anyway especially when using Hibernate)
- use `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` for `tasks`

Comment: to be clear @amique, it "resolves" the issue in terms of there only being 1 element that you expect, *but*, that doesn't change the fact that all that data is still being returned; it's just that Hibernate puts them into a Set now, so no duplicates. Really you should still look at using FetchMode.SUBSELECT for better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your `targetEntity` in the `@ManyToMany` relationship?

you should have something like:

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Task.class)
@JoinTable(name = "worker_task", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "task_id") })
private ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

I suggest you to change to `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relationship anyways. That concept is more compatible with the database design and is more understandable when a person looks at the ERD. So `Manager` has one-to-many relationship with Manager_Worker thus manager_worker has many-to-one relationship with manager. Keep the same for the rest of the entities.